# Assigning variables in coffeescript using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am trying to integrate angular.js into the pubnub webrtc example found [here](http://webrtc.co/):

Below is a form that I am trying to use with angular to assign a name for a webrtc lobby:

```
<form ng-controller="ctrl" ng-submit="submit()"class="box">
        <div>
        <input type="text" id="userid" placeholder="Username" ng-model="text" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" id="login">Log In</a>
        </div>
</form>
```

How would I assign the string given by a user via the input(using Angular.js rather than the coffeescript shown), so that it is able to be used within the scope of my coffeescript file below? I would then like a hint on how to further display the given login name in another html element. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand the form from the example is somewhat poorly written.

I have the following coffee  script to grab from input a uuid via the form above:

```
$(document).ready () ->
  # Globals
  # =================
  window.pubnub = null
  uuid = null
  currentCall = null
  myStream = null
  plusClient = null

  # Login
  # ================

  document.querySelector('#login').addEventListener 'click', (event) ->
    uuid = document.querySelector('#userid').value
    login "guest-#{uuid}"

  login = (name) ->
    uuid = name
```

Comment: Those aren't globals. Those are local to that function, except for the one you've explicitly assigned to `window`.

Comment: Why you're using jQuery in angular?

Comment: The jquery was given in the example, I am currently trying to change it @jcubic

Comment: If you have question about coffeescript, best answer is to compile and look at the result. And if question is about angular, please provide angular code.